# Can you Disable Wi-Fi and Bluetooth from Google Apps or a MDM Server?

Tags: wi-fi, settings

[This page](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en-uk&hlrm=en-uk&hlrm=en&answer=1734200) claims:

> **Wifi configuration from Admin console** - Enter Wifi network settings in
>   the Admin console, and they’ll automatically be pushed out to all
>   managed Android devices.

Does this mean just connection settings, or can it be disabled remotely?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at that page, I'd say it's just the connection settings. I don't think you can completely disable Wi-Fi and Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

[Exchange ActiveSync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_ActiveSync) allows you to disable Wi-Fi and bluetooth.

However, I'm not sure for Google Apps. Can't seem to find the information on their Support page.

Comment: Do you know if that particular ActiveSync policy is compatible on Android? I cannot find the API for it

Comment: @h00j I think the policy is supposed to be defined in Microsoft Exchange ActiveSync.

Comment: I understand that, but   
 
Do you know if that particular ActiveSync policy is compatible on Android

Comment: @h00j I would assume YES. I have a corporate Exchange account on my phone, which disables certain options (like I should use only PIN lockscreen; other types are disabled). I would assume disabling Wi-Fi and bluetooth would also work.